# PHP: Concatenate a leading zero to single digit numbers in string

Tags: php, regex

I have this sample string: `hello77boss2america-9-22-fr99ee-9`. A leading 0 should be added in front of all the single digit numbers of the string. The result should be: `hello77boss02america-09-22-fr99ee-09`

I tried the code below:

```
str_replace("(0-9)","0",$num);
```

Comment: Have you looked into the preg_replace function: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [preg_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) to find the lone digits and replace them, something like...

```
<?php
echo preg_replace(
    '~(?<!\d)(\d)(?!\d)~',
    '0$1',
    'hello77boss2america-9-22-fr99ee-9'
); //hello77boss02america-09-22-fr99ee-09
```

Here's a slightly more descriptive version.

```
<?php
$callback = function($digit) {

    $digit = $digit[0];

    if (1 == strlen($digit)) {
        $digit = "0$digit";
    }

    return $digit;
};

echo preg_replace_callback('~\d+~', $callback, 'hello77boss2america-9-22-fr99ee-9');
// hello77boss02america-09-22-fr99ee-09
```