# How to use preg_replace to create a mysql formatted date and to pad a 0 if the date is less than 10

Tags: php, mysql, preg-replace

if a user writes a date format like 01/05/1985 (DD/MM/YYY), I'll get a formatted result of **1985-05-01** using

```
$_GET['search'] = '01/05/1985';
$search = preg_replace('/^(\d{1,2})\W(\d{1,2})\W(\d{4})$/', '$3-$2-$1', $_GET['search']);
```

which is what I want. But if the user writes this: 1/5/1985 I'll get **1985-5-1** which is NOT what I want. How can I pad a zero to the Day or Month part only if the value is less than 10?

I have tried using:

```
$_GET['search'] = '01/05/1985';
$search = preg_replace('/^(\d{1,2})\W(\d{1,2})\W(\d{4})$/', '$3-0$2-0$1', $_GET['search']);
```

But I then get the following **1985-005-001** I'd like to get **1985-05-01**

I've seen something simular [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18165821/5438510/) when it comes to padding if a number is less then 10. But I do not know how to then format the date as my RegEx knowledge is very weak.

Can somebody please show me how to get the result only using php regex please and NOT using php date functions. Thanks.

Comment: `$3.'-'.str_pad($2, 2, '0',STR_PAD_LEFT ).'-'.str_pad($1, 2, '0',STR_PAD_LEFT )` http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php  - you cant capture what is not there, best to just pad it on the capture groups.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use `str_pad` inside `preg_replace_callback` since the latter allows you to provide a function that can format the regex matches

```
$search = preg_replace_callback(
    '/^(\d{1,2})\W(\d{1,2})\W(\d{4})$/',
    function($v){
        return $v[3].'-'
                . str_pad($v[2], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT).'-'
                . str_pad($v[1], 2, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    },
    $_GET['search']
);
```

[**Live demo**](https://3v4l.org/YNA1v)

Comment: Thanks for the demo, I really appreciate your help.