# PHP preg_replace padding a digit

Tags: php, regex

I want to find the latest video in a html but this html doesn't sort well.

https://jsfiddle.net/8zk6j7dv/

```
<html><head><title>111.111.111.111 - /video8/</title></head><body><H1>111.111.111.111 - /video8/</H1><hr>
```

```
[To Parent Directory]

 5/14/2020 11:26 AM          635 2020y-5m-14d-11h-20m-44s.mp4
 5/14/2020 12:02 PM     30333149 2020y-5m-14d-11h-57m-38s.mp4
 5/14/2020 12:21 PM     32048599 2020y-5m-14d-12h-16m-7s.mp4
 5/14/2020 12:31 PM     31973846 2020y-5m-14d-12h-26m-6s.mp4
 5/14/2020 12:41 PM     33358304 2020y-5m-14d-12h-36m-6s.mp4
 5/14/2020 12:51 PM     29515351 2020y-5m-14d-12h-46m-6s.mp4
 5/14/2020  1:01 PM     34340983 2020y-5m-14d-12h-56m-6s.mp4
 5/14/2020 12:11 PM     31259022 2020y-5m-14d-12h-6m-6s.mp4
 5/14/2020  1:21 PM     36133243 2020y-5m-14d-13h-16m-9s.mp4
 5/14/2020  1:31 PM     38054158 2020y-5m-14d-13h-26m-6s.mp4
 5/14/2020  1:36 PM            0 2020y-5m-14d-13h-36m-6s.mp4_audio
 5/14/2020  1:38 PM     19232355 2020y-5m-14d-13h-36m-6s.mp4_video
 5/14/2020  1:46 PM     36643767 2020y-5m-14d-13h-41m-6s.mp4
 5/14/2020  1:56 PM     36170676 2020y-5m-14d-13h-51m-7s.mp4
```

---

The filenames don't zero padding 5m to 05m so I can't compare the time. I need to format them first.

```
$arr = ["2020y-1m-1d-0h-0m-0s",
        "2020y-5m-20d-12h-10m-6s",
        "2020y-5m-24d-12h-0m-6s",
        "2020y-12m-31d-23h-50m-56s"
];


foreach ($arr as $key=>$value) {
    $tt = preg_replace('/-(?<![0-9])(\d)(?![0-9])\w/', 'str_pad($1, 2, "0", STR_PAD_LEFT)', $value);
    //$tt = preg_replace('/-(?<![0-9])(\d)(?![0-9])\w/', '0$1', $value);
    echo $tt; 
    echo "\n\r";
}
```

The output should be

```
2020y-01m-01d-00h-00m-00s
2020y-05m-20d-12h-10m-06s
2020y-05m-24d-12h-00m-06s
2020y-12m-31d-23h-50m-56s
```

How can I fix the preg_replace?

https://regex101.com/r/HywlVw/1/

Comment: I think you are better of with `strptime` and `strftime`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/18165774/2943403

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do want to use regex for this rather than `strptime` and `strftime`, you can use the following:

```
(?<=-)(\d)(?=[msdh])
```

https://regex101.com/r/kzhXF2/1

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any capture groups.

Find: `~-\K(?=\d[dhms])~`
Replace: `0`

This means look for a hyphen, then forget you found it (`\K`), then lookahead for a digit that is immediately followed by `d`, `h`, `m`, or `s`.  Then you merely replace that zero-width position with a zero.

```
preg_replace('~-\K(?=\d[dhms])~', '0', $arr);
```